# Printing data from a for loop into a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to print summary statistics from a for loop into a dataframe. Currently I am printing it as a long string. I would really like to iteratively fill a dataframe and print that but I am not sure how.

```
items = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e","f"]
year = df.sort_values().unique()

for j, item in enumerate(items):
    groups = df.groupby("year")
    i = 0
    for label, binned_data in groups:
        desired_output = "year: {}, label: {}, distinct_x: {}, distinct_y: {}".format(year[i], item, 
        binned_data['var1'].sum(), binned_data['var2'].count())
        i += 1
        print(desired_output)
```

What I would like the output to look like is:

```
Year Label Var1_Sum Var2_Count
2013   a      XX       XX
2013   b      YY       YY
2013   c      YY       YY
2013   d      YY       YY
2013   e      YY       YY
2013   f      YY       YY
2014   a      XX       XX
....
```

Comment: please include input data in addition to output data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create dataframe at the end:

```
items = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e","f"]
year = df.sort_values().unique()

result = []
for j, item in enumerate(items):
    groups = df.groupby("year")
    i = 0
    for label, binned_data in groups:
        result.append[year[i], item, binned_data['var1'].sum(), binned_data['var2'].count()]
        i += 1
df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=["Year", "Label", "Var1_Sum", "Var2_Count"])
print (df)
```

If you want to update the dataframe within the loop:

```
items = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e","f"]
year = df.sort_values().unique()

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Year", "Label", "Var1_Sum", "Var2_Count"])
for j, item in enumerate(items):
    groups = df.groupby("year")
    i = 0
    for label, binned_data in groups:
        result = [year[i], item, binned_data['var1'].sum(), binned_data['var2'].count()]
        df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=["Year", "Label", "Var1_Sum", "Var2_Count"]).append(df, ignore_index=True)
        print (df)
        i += 1
```